# Search in python is not working

Tags: python-2.7

```
def cache(dump):
  for mcast_cache in dump.split('vrId') :
    if "224.0.1.25" in mcast_cache:
        if "10.89.204.50" in mcast_cache:
            return mcast_cache
```

**Below is the input for above function:**

```
vrId 2 G=224.0.1.24 S=10.89.204.46 Vid 103 : (HW IPMC 0 l3hash 0 hit 0)
-> Vid 103
    -> 5 9 10 49
vrId 2 G=224.0.1.25 S=10.89.204.50 Vid 103 : (HW IPMC 0 l3hash 0 hit 0)
-> Vid 103
    -> 5 9 10 49
vrId 2 G=224.0.1.25 S=10.89.204.49 Vid 103 : (HW IPMC 0 l3hash 0 hit 1)
-> Vid 103
    -> 5 9 10 49
vrId 2 G=224.0.1.25 S=10.89.204.48 Vid 103 : (HW IPMC 0 l3hash 0 hit 0)
-> Vid 103
    -> 5 9 10 49
```

If the source and multicast group address match then I have to return complete output for that specific IP address. example: In above case I have return below output,

```
     2 G=224.0.1.25 S=10.89.204.50 Vid 103 : (HW IPMC 0 l3hash 0 hit 0)
-> Vid 103
    -> 5 9 10 49
```

Above is working perfectly fine. Now, I want user will enter the source and multicast IP address and it will be pass to the function to search in table, so i have written below code,

```
src_address = raw_input("\nEnter SOURCE IP address of multicast sender: ")
grp_address = raw_input("\nEnter Multicast group IP address: ")

hal_dump = cache(xos.cmd("debug hal show ipv4mc"),src_address,grp_address)

def cache(dump,src_ip,grp_ip):
 for mcast_cache in dump.split('vrId') :
    if "grp_ip" in mcast_cache:
        if "src_ip" in mcast_cache:
            return mcast_cache
```

It will not return any output. 
Can any one suggest how to resolve this issue and is there any other way I can search the input more efficiently?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for the strings "grp_id" and "src_ip" instead of the variables you are passing in to the function.

```
src_address = raw_input("\nEnter SOURCE IP address of multicast sender: ")
grp_address = raw_input("\nEnter Multicast group IP address: ")

hal_dump = cache(xos.cmd("debug hal show ipv4mc"),src_address,grp_address)

def cache(dump,src_ip,grp_ip):
 for mcast_cache in dump.split('vrId') :
    if grp_ip in mcast_cache:
        if src_ip in mcast_cache:
            return mcast_cache
```

Comment: Thank you so much Collin. I have missed that part.